# jQuery: what version do I have to use in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, jquery, version

I have a full responsive site in SP 2013 with several WebParts developed by a very huge developer group.

We have centralized custom script links and JavaScript APIs (and/or frameworks) in two masterpages.

Now from certain WebParts (not all) sometimes have a syntax error in the minified jQuery (version 10.1).

In particular I've noticed that in debug mode (IE8), the same click button doesn't give the same behaviour ... it works properly! :/

Are there limitations or known problems using the jQuery library version for SP2013!?

My clients is often running Windows XP / Seven OS with IE8 browser, due to company restrictions.

Comment: It would help if you post the error logs as well.  It helps to pinpoint what exactly is causing the behavior.

Comment: You are right, but the error isn't logged ... is a side effect on some feature in that page (same WP in other pages works well), in fact, the debugger breaks on syntax Error on minified script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering if you have gone through the 1.10+ change log to see if your code is using something that was removed.

http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/24/jquery-1-10-0-and-2-0-1-released/

Comment: We have done ...

Comment: I'm confused by your brief comment. Did you try adding in the migration patch that the jQuery team provides?

Comment: I've put the new jQuery and jQuery-Ui references in all master pages provided; the problem was presented in only one custom page, with a special page layout, which included two validators field on a single textbox (I didn't have seen code before because it wasn't mine ... :/ ) and this has caused a strange side effect.

At now, I've not clear why that exception was thrown.

Comment: Did you try adding the migration patch for this specific layout?

Comment: Yes, migration patch is correct and consistent, but the problem remains in these f**** validators.

Comment: Good luck with your endeavors. Sounds frustrating... :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any dependency of Sharepoint with jQuery version. It depends what version is used by your customization.

You need to check which version of jQuery is used by your webparts and other customizations.

you can use 1.7.1 or 1.7.2 versions of jQuery in SharePoint 2013

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/jj163201.aspx

Comment: Thank you Aanchal, but we use in all WPs, 1.10.1 version of jQuery ... do you know any problems with it!?

Comment: We had, but our different components were build on different jquery version. If all are referring same there should not be a problem.

Comment: Yes, but I must use 1.10 version becouse we have several implementation of jquery.datatable, that works fine only with that version ... :/

Comment: So you can use this version. What is that issue you getting with this version?

Comment: If it's datatables.net that you are using, have you looked at older versions that don't require 1.10+?

Comment: Yes, of course, but jQuery.datatable with full responsive CSS class injected on draw method, works well only with 1.10+ version ...
There's a web Agency behind which imposes their rules ... :(